# Does Gmail have an Automatic Language Outlook-Equivalent?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, is there a feature equivalent to Microsoft Outlook's [automatic language options](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-automatic-language-options-194d309c-3e10-4bd5-a694-ba9bbdf4a28e?CorrelationId=a872ad38-b352-423d-915b-398d2840cdab&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?

I have a client who migrated from having an on-site exchange server to having Google Apps (in the cloud) for hosting the company's email.

One user who is successfully using Microsoft Outlook (with Google Apps) is now trying to use the Gmail Web Interface instead, but is missing the [Auto-Detect Language feature](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-automatic-language-options-194d309c-3e10-4bd5-a694-ba9bbdf4a28e?CorrelationId=a872ad38-b352-423d-915b-398d2840cdab&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) provided by Microsoft Outlook.

This user is bilingual. In one email he may type both Spanish and English. Outlook will accommodate (automatically) the language he types in **and will spell-check accordingly**.

In Gmail, is there a feature equivalent to Microsoft Outlook's automatic language options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in gmail but there is a work around if you are using chrome browser you can add another language and chrome can then check the grammer:
Check this [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en)